# Can't remove navigation drawer header left padding?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I want to remove the left padding that the navigation drawer adds automatically. I tried adding

```
android:padding="0dp"
```

and margins of 0dp to the elements but there seems to be a little bit of space on the left of the drawer header. Is there something I'm missing?

Here's the header code

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/report_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/accent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/navigation_fllesh_button"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/side_button_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/side_button_size"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_foreground_logo"
                android:contentDescription="@string/drawer_closing_button_description"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:tint="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/addingtoncf_bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/app_title"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/navigation_fllesh_button"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/navigation_fllesh_button"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/navigation_fllesh_button" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

and here is the extra padding:

This is the [design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h1Lm.png)

And this is the [blueprint view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6cwL.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to remove the toolbar margin from left try to remove it with the help of contentinsert padding to, by setting 0dp.

```
android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp" 
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
```

**If still the problem still there then set contentInsetStartWithNavigation to zero**

```
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```

Hope it will solve your issue.